# Does the top level domain I choose for my domain name affect the features I can build for my site?

Tags: domains, web-development, top-level-domains

I am about to make a site regarding programming and technology. I want to build it on a domain at one of the popular top level domains (.com,.net,.org, etc).

If I want to add a feature to my site to allow every member to make their own profile on the site, will I have to give some extra money for that on different top level domains? Do all the top level domains allow such features?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes TLDs may affect traffic since .COM is most popular. And most of the people, if they are not aware with TLD of your site, try .COM first. But most important is domain name not TLD.
 Moreover i would suggest you to use wordpress 3.0. It'll help you to build a site easily as per your need. You just need to pay for domain name and webspace.

Answer (score 1):

The TLDs (.com, .net, etc) doesn't affect the content. It's just a part of the domain name, and the content will be up to you.

Answer (score 1):

To put it into reality:

- A domain name is just like the "name of your business" (e.g. McDonald, Hungry Jacks, etc). Does it mean something to you? Maybe yes, maybe no. But it is always recommended to choose a good domain name so that no one can leave a bad impressions about it. Just imagine that you have a business name, e.g. BankruptFast, what do people think about it?
- A hosting service is just like a "place/premise to do your business". Obviously, once you think of a business name, you may have to consider renting/buying your own business space.

Therefore, a domain name will be non-functional without a valid hosting service. Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for the BankrupFast.I am about to purchase a domain name that contains '0'(zero),instead of 'o'(alphabet O).The domain name was not avaiable in plane english so I replaced the 'o' with '0'.Does it sound good and can compete with good domain names out there?

Comment: I highly recommend you not to combine an alphabetical domain with some numeric number. Just imagine that someone is asking about your domain. If you have a domain name: g0DonutKing.com, you will certainly have to spell your name to anyone who asked it. Do you think that google.com is much more better than g00gle.com? There are still tons of domains you can select and you can try to mix and match it. You can use the domain registration portal at http://domreg.asphostserver.com for new domain name registration. Hope this helps...:-)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know much about what features does the .com,.info,.org etc offer

They're domain names, they don't offer any features beyond name resolution. Your domain registrar may offer more features, however.